# Specifications on Category page opencart 3.0.3.6

Tags: attributes, opencart, categories

I have been trying to get specifications/attrributes to shoe on Category page in the product panel ender description.
This is a solution to a similar and particular problem: [Display product attributes on category page - Opencart 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923301/display-product-attributes-on-category-page-opencart-3)
I have tried to adapt it to my needs but unsuccessful.
I have put this in the category controller page:
'attribute_groups' => $this->model_catalog_installer->getProductAttributes($result['product_id']),`And in the Category Twig page:`{% if product.attribute_groups %}
{% for attribute_group in product.attribute_groups %}
{% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}

{{ attribute.name }}

{{ attribute.text }}

`

The result is that the attributes do not appear and I get no errors.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this? Any help as always appreciated.

Hi Daniel,  The following code that worked was in catalog\controller\product\catefory.php:

```
'attribute_groups' =>$this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($result['product_id']),
```

after

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',`
```

Then in the catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\category.twig:

```
{% if product.attribute_groups %} <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-specification">   <table class="table table-bordered">
{% for attribute_group in product.attribute_groups %}
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><strong>{{ attribute_group.name }}</strong></td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ attribute.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ attribute.text }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
  </tbody>
{% endfor %} </table></div>{% endif %}
```

after

```
<div>
 <div class="caption">
            <h4><a href="{{ product.href }}">{{ product.name }}</a></h4>
            <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
```

Hope this helps others..

Comment: you are used any themes ?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: No themes..just default

Comment: Yes cleared cache and refreshed modifications etc.

Comment: @MCOpen You can debug the code step by step. I think Twig code is not the right place.

Comment: If you need Customization. You can contact me personally via WhatsApp, Email, and Linkedin at my Profiles Description.

Comment: Have now resolved this by altering elements of the code that now works.

Comment: Thanks to those that offered help..

Comment: Perhaps you can share what you changed so that other users who have this issue can find a resolution?